# Why is canvas.drawBitmap really slow on android O but on prev versions is running smoothly

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a app that is able to zoom and drag a image but on the latest android "O" i have noticed that canvas.drawBitmap is really slow is there some feature of android "O" that creates this problem and is there a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the release version of O before judging its speed. Might be that there is some testing / debugging stuff enabled in the preview versions, or perhaps hardware acceleration is not enabled etc.

I don't think that they would allow that such a basic functionality would slow down.